# animation of background ignores border radius in FF

Tags: css, firefox

The background using animation to fade in and out repeatedly. The background fill seems to ignore the border radius of the DIV. It appears to work as expected in chrome but not in FF (v 78.11). Wondering if there's some Mozilla specific property I should be using? The DIV shows the radius and the animation does what it should, the corner just doesn't get clipped to fit the radius. I'm guessing a FF bug?

```css
div {
  width: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center
}

div:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 16px;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
  border-top-right-radius: 16px;
}

.warning {
  animation: WARNING-FLASH 1s infinite;
  border-top-left-radius: 16px;
}

@keyframes WARNING-FLASH {
  0% {
    background-color: #cc190c00;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: #cc190c;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #cc190c00;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="warning">testing</div><div>some stuff</div>
```

Comment: I ran the code in FF and it seems to work fine. Is your browser up to date?

Comment: This seems to work in later versions of Firefox (We're at v90 at the time of writing), are you just working on general backward compatibility or do you specifically need to support v78?

Comment: Working OK for me - FF 89.0.2 (64-bit) on Windows 10.

Comment: The version is corporate controlled, we're generally a few version behind because every update needs to go through testing before its accessible in our repo. At this point, it's more for compatibility, but only a handful of us will even have access to the application so I can enforce chrome use if necessary.  Thanks for the confirmation on the version, I'll consider the issue closed.